# Query with multiple values on a property with one value in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build on this query a little bit. The index I am searching also has a field "entity" with an id. So a few records will have "entity" : 16, "entity" 156 etc, depending on the id of the entity. I need to expand this query in such a way that I can pass an array or some list of values in, such as {:term => {:entity => [1, 16, 100]}} and get back records that have one of these integers as their entity value. I haven't had any luck so far, can someone help me?

```
{ 
  "query" : {

    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "term" : {"user_type" : "alpha"}
        }, 
        { 
          "term" :{"area" : "16"}
        }
      ], 
      "must_not" : [], 
      "should" :   []
    }
  }, 
  "filter": {
    "or" : [{
       "and" : [
          { "term" : { "area" : "16" } },
          { "term" : { "date" : "05072013" } }
       ]
    }, {
       "and" : [
          { "term" : { "area" : "16" } },
          { "term" : { "date" : "blank" } }
       ]
    }


    ]
  },
"from" : 0,
"size" : 100 
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `"terms"` instead of `"term"`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

`{ "terms" : { "entity" : [ 123, 1234, ... ] }}`

Comment: Thank you very much!  You saved my day :)

Comment: this query will contact with AND or with OR ? i want to check my condition with OR like: in above query entity=123 OR entity=1234 so on. how to write that query ?

Comment: @DeepParekh Were you able to write the query for the above comment? AND or OR?
I have something like this. (I have to pass multiple values of extension to filter. Can you help me to solve this)Right now I could only send one value of extension. What if I have to pass multiple values of extension for filter query?
`.Filter(ft => ft.Term(t => t.Field("content_type").Value(extension)))))`