# ElasticSearch : How to use IN equivalent operator in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City IN ('Paris','London')

How to convert above query in elasticsearch..

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-query)!

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255416/query-with-multiple-values-on-a-property-with-one-value-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query with multiple values on a property with one value in Elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255416/query-with-multiple-values-on-a-property-with-one-value-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```
GET _search
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "city" : ["Paris", "London"]
        }
    }
}
```

However, please make sure that your mapping has `city` marked as `not_analyzed`

In order to make your searches case insensitive, there are two ways I can think of :

1. lower case your terms while indexing as well as querying, this is an easy way.
2. Create a custom analyzer for lowercase the input without tokenizing it. Use `match query` instead of `terms query`. `Terms query` doesn't work on `analyzed` fields.

A sample lowercase analyzer would look like this :

```
"analyzer": {
    "lowercase_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
        ]
    }
    }
```

Comment: After mapping not_analyzed then search don't work as a case incensitive.How to resolve it..thanks for your reply

Comment: Updated the answer for the same.

Comment: $results=$client->search([
                'index' => 'morsol',
                'type' => 'ms_emp_db',
                'body' => [
                     'query' => [
                        "multi_match" => [
                            "fields" => ["colmun1","column2"],
                            "query" => $searchKeyword,
                            "type" => "phrase_prefix"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]);

i am using laravel and elasticsearch.column1 and column2 is not_analyzed..how to search case insensitive.

Comment: Please refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036708/elasticsearch-map-case-insensitive-to-not-analyzed-documents

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like:

The `POST` request:

```
http://localhost:9200/Customers/_search? <--assuming customers as your index
```

and the request `BODY`:

```
"query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "query":"City:(Paris London)"
      }
   }
```

**IN** acts like `:` in ES. Hope this helps!